# Removing a patch from Drupal core

Tags: 8, composer

I'm using cweagans/composer-patches to apply a patch to drupal/core. When a second developer has pulled down the codebase and run composer install, the installation of drupal/core is failing.

Firstly, I'm not sure why this is happening because composer install works on my local machine?

Secondly, if I remove the patch from my compser.json, and re-run composer install, the patch isn't removed. How can I remove the patch from drupal/core please?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please add the error the other developer has to your question?

Answer (score 0):

When using `cweagens/composer-patches`, the patch only gets applied upon `composer install`.  When you remove the patch from `composer.json`, it does not remove the already patched file, because composer isn't tracking that.

So, when you remove a patch from `composer.json`, you need to delete the relevant module/theme/core directory and then run `composer install` again.

As for the second developer's issue, try cloning your code from wherever it is stored and then running `composer install` there; always test from a "fresh" copy of your repository, and then it will be easier to see the issues that people may have when pulling down code for the first time.